# Adding multipage printing to Windows 8 ListView App

Tags: printing, windows-8

I have an app with a ListView showing a list of summary items.

I've added print support, but I'm stuck on splitting my content into different pages.

I can add multiple pages, but I don't know how to split my content into pages based on page size.

Currently I have a xaml user control for my print content with a bound ItemsControl in it. I'd either like to bind to a list of just the items that will fit on the page, or move the top visible item position up based on the page number.

I'm not sure which is the best approach and I'm not sure how to do either.

The only paging example I could find in the docs was for a rich text block, which relies on the RichTextBlockOverflow control. I don't think that will help me.